# How to access Django Service(hosted on another IP) from chrome extension

Tags: javascript, python, django, google-chrome-extension, httpresponse

I have hosted DjangoServices on particular IP address (xx.xx.x.x:8000) and want to access them from chrome extension. I am unable to access those services while making a connection from javascript like as follows:

```
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    theUrl = "http://xx.xx.x.x:8000/polls/neo4jSample/";
    xmlhttp.open("POST", theUrl, true);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
        }
    }
```

But, this works when I hosted on local machine as follows:

```
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    theUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/neo4jSample/";
    xmlhttp.open("POST", theUrl, true);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
        }
    }
```

Please, anyone can help me out of this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is because the remote `IP` is not public yet, or if its on same network, you should start that app with `./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` so the system on the same network can access it. Refer about [`runserver`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/django-admin/#runserver) here.

Comment: I am running DjangoService with the following command:          
**python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000** but it is not working Should I change any settings of my chrome extension.

Comment: Can you normally access the URL in browser ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the hosted api base url in your manifest.json file of your extension like the following.

```
"permissions": [
    ...
    "https://dummy-site-xyz.com/*",
    ...
  ],
```

Comment: I have already added in the permissions as follows:      
`"permissions": [   "tabs","cookies","contextMenus","identity","http://x.x.x.x:8000/","http://*/*",
    "http://www.amazon.in/*",
    "webRequest", "webRequestBlocking","webNavigation","storage"
  ]`  Request as been sent to the DjangoService while refreshing the chrome extension but it is not working while loading the amazon web page. Actually it should be triggered while page is loading.

Comment: check the chrome extension event lister `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', PageShowHandler, false);`

Comment: I have used `window.addEventListener('load', () => {})` in avascript files. It is working fine when I host DjangoService on local machine  but the issue is there only when hosted on other IP Address.

Comment: I have also tried with DOMContentLoaded even though it is not working for local host . I think this is the not the problem which I have facing.